# How could I make TextField wrap content without using IntrinsicWidth

Tags: flutter, textfield

This is my code

```
Row(
  children: [
    Text("title"),
    Spacer(),
    ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
          maxHeight: 28,
          minWidth: 45
      ),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0x0A000000),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4))
        ),
        child: TextField(
        ),
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(width: 4,),
    Text("unit")
  ],
)
```

TextField will expand as much as possible, how could I make TextField wrap content without
using IntrinsicWidth.

Update:

[using Expanded or Flexible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tN63.png)

[using IntrinsicWidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgUvT.png)

2nd is what I want to achieve, how can I achieve it without using IntrinsicWidth

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and remove Spacer form your widget use Expanded widget instead of that

```
Row(
            children: [
              const Text("Title"),
              const SizedBox(width: 4),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0x0A000000),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4))),
                  child: const TextField(),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 4),
              const Text("Unit")
            ],
          ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with my description, I hope TextField is wrapped content, not expanded

Answer (score -1):

**just you need to wrap the container with Flexible widget:**

```
    Row(
  children: [
    Text("title"),
    SizedBox(width: 4),
    Flexible(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0x0A000000),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4))
        ),
        child: TextField(),
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(width: 4),
    Text("unit"),
  ],
)
```

*This Working Fine*

Comment: I tried, didn't achieve what I wanted, thanks for your answer, maybe using IntrinsicWidth is the only way

Comment: i will update my answer check it now

Comment: i update my question too, it turns out that i can not avoid using IntrinsicWidth